# Plot an integer matrix in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

I have 100x100 integer matrix (which each variable represents a percentage value). So i want to plot the data via a heatmap (i guess this one is an appropriate one). In addition, i want to make regions obvious to separate due to a condition like; if "percentage > 50" then paint that area in red relative to value of "percentage". For instance, if percentage is 80 then it will have darker red than the percentage which will have 50. Well you can see an example of what i'm trying to do.

[image]

I will appreciate a lot for any help. Thanks anyway

EDIT: Here is the sample code for reading and constructing matrix.

```
library(ggplot2)

outcomeMatrix <- read.table("probMatrix.txt")

firstCol = as.numeric(outcomeMatrix[1,])
firstRow = as.numeric(outcomeMatrix[,1])

matrix <- as.matrix(scale(outcomeMatrix))
```

Well you can see a sample of data (10x10 matrix) below

[Data](http://pastebin.ca/2469905)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, `image` could be helpful:

```
#matrix with the part of your data 10x10 you uploaded
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
41 10 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
75 36 20 9 4 2 1 0 0 0
91 65 47 31 20 13 8 5 3 2
97 78 64 47 35 25 18 12 8 5
99 88 76 63 50 39 29 22 16 11
99 93 85 74 63 52 42 32 25 19
99 96 91 83 73 64 53 44 35 28
99 98 94 88 81 72 64 54 46 37
99 98 96 92 87 80 72 64 55 47"))

#neccessary step to `image` the expected. read `?image`
t_mat <- t(mat[ncol(mat):1,])

#basic plot
image(t_mat, col = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))(10), axes = F)

#creaty matrix with `NA`s and fill 
#only the values you want to appear yellow.
#here: say 45 to 55
yellows <- matrix(nrow = nrow(t_mat), ncol = ncol(t_mat))
yellows[which(t_mat > 45 & t_mat < 55)] <- t_mat[which(t_mat > 45 & t_mat < 55)] 

#overlay "yellows" to basic plot
image(yellows, col = rgb(1,1,0,1/2), add = T)
```

The plot looks:

[image]

P.S. I guessed that's what the yellow borders are for. Sorry if I misunderstood.

**EDIT**

Added example `legend` and labels:

```
title(main = "imageplot", xlab = "x axis", ylab = "y axis")
legend(x = 0.6, y = 1.15, legend = c("<45", "45-55", ">55"), 
           fill = c("blue", rgb(1,1,0,1/2), "red"), xpd = T, ncol = 3)
```

**EDIT2**

Added labels to both axes:

```
#I guess you'll need to use `axis(1, at = seq(0,1,0.0101), labels = seq(1, 100, 1))` 
#but I'm not sure
axis(1, at = seq(0,1,0.11), labels = seq(1, 10, 1)) 
axis(2, at = seq(0,1,0.11), labels = seq(1, 10, 1))
```

Comment: hey alexis sorry for late relpy.I was working on juba's way,however I faced with some errors. But this one is cool also. Is it possible to plot like this.( I may add some visual things like legend,main,xlab vs)

Comment: @quartaela: I updated the answer to include an example legend and titles. Was this helpful?

Comment: yes that is perfect ! :). Last thing can you numerate x and y axis from 0 to 100 ?

Comment: @quartaela: Look at _EDIT2_ (I, also, updated the plot). You might have to adjust the values, though, because you have a 100*100 matrix while I used a 10*10.

Comment: I thought `axis` function works with `plot` cause I was dealing with them a couple of hours ago and couldnt make it. Whatever, this works perfectly. I have to dig them more for more features :D. By the way thanks a LOT for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
## Random data
set.seed(1337)
m <- matrix(runif(10000, 0, 100), ncol=100,nrow=100)

## Reshape data to long format
mm <- melt(m)

## Plot
ggplot(data=mm) +
    geom_tile(aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", mid="white", high="red", midpoint=50)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply juba. I'm facing with some issues. Even i added my sample code in EDIT part. So do I have to use the function `m <- matrix(runif(10000, 0, 100), ncol=100,nrow=100)` or if I have to then how can I use it ?

Comment: No you don't have to run `matrix(runif(...))` as it is only to generate random data. But you'll have to use `melt`. I can't say more without a sample of your data.

Comment: you can see the text file from the link below
http://txtup.co/DFoYb. On the other hand, it could not find function melt ? Is it necessary to convert data to long format because it only contains integer values between 0-100 ?

Comment: If you want to provide sample data, it is far better to copy/paste a small excerpt, or tu use `dput()` on it. Well, once you get your matrix with you variable values in it, you should just have to call `melt()` on it.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, even if you want I can share a sample data. On the other hand, even I installed the package which contains melt function whole area looks same color. this is the the way how i use ggplot function. 
`ggplot(mm) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=nrow(outcomeMatrix), y=ncol(outcomeMatrix), fill=value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", mid="white", high="red", midpoint=50)`

I guess `Var1` and `Var2` are represent the length or range of axis

Comment: No, if you use `melt` you can keep the `ggplot` line the same as in my answer. Use `head(mm)` in your session to understand what it does. And sorry, I didn't mention that `melt` is part of the `reshpae2` package.